# MonoDroid: Global Error Handler

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there a way to create a global error handler for MonoDroid? My debugger is broken so I need a way to see the exception info while the application crashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser` is what you're looking for:

```
//that's a dirty-code example, do not use as-is! :)
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    File.AppendAllText("tmp.txt", args.Exception.ToString());
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) unhandled exceptions should end up in the Android debug log:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my project, it can handle and submit error info. https://github.com/soundnRg/Crasher